# How to compile custom module for iOS in Godot3.1

Tags: ios, godot

I'm trying to add Share module in my game for iOS platform. i have this repo for sharing module [Godot-Share](https://github.com/Shin-NiL/Godot-Share).

I'm using godot 3.1 and i download latest godot source code from [Link](https://github.com/godotengine/godot).

To implement share module i follow this step to compile custom module.

1. Copy share folder to godot/modules folder.
2. Then i compile for iOS using this Link. I used following command to compile.

   ```
   scons p=iphone tools=no target=debug arch=arm

   scons p=iphone tools=no target=debug arch=arm64
   ```

   In **godot/bin** i get as result two files :

> libgodot.iphone.debug.arm.a
>
> libgodot.iphone.debug.arm64.a

3. After i used following command to generate ***.debug.fat.a** file.

   ```
   lipo -create bin/libgodot.iphone.debug.arm64.a bin/libgodot.iphone.debug.arm.a -output bin/libgodot.iphone.debug.fat.a
   ```

as result i get **libgodot.iphone.debug.fat.a** file in **godot/bin** folder.

4. i replaced **libgodot.iphone.debug.fat.a** file into **godot/misc/dist/ios_xcode** folder
5. i copied **ios_xcode** folder in documents, rename **ios_xcode** to iphone, then zip it. i get result file **iphone.zip** in Document folder.
6. Then i add **iphone.zip** file to `Project>Export>Options>Custom Package>Debug`

[image]

7. Then Export project.

   **Error I'm Facing :**

   ```
   Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
   "_z_verbose", referenced from:
   _inflateInit2_ in FBLogin.a(ftgzip.iphone.debug.arm.o)
   _inflate in FBLogin.a(ftgzip.iphone.debug.arm.o)
   _inflateEnd in FBLogin.a(ftgzip.iphone.debug.arm.o)
   _inflateReset in FBLogin.a(ftgzip.iphone.debug.arm.o)
   _inflate_blocks_reset in FBLogin.a(ftgzip.iphone.debug.arm.o)
   _inflate_codes_free in FBLogin.a(ftgzip.iphone.debug.arm.o)
   _inflate_blocks_new in FBLogin.a(ftgzip.iphone.debug.arm.o)
   ...
   "_z_error", referenced from:
   _inflate_codes in FBLogin.a(ftgzip.iphone.debug.arm.o)
   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
   ```

So my question is : Am i compiling and linking custom module for iOS is right?

How do i solve above issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'm facing this error because because i'm trying to build custom binary from different version source code and provide to different version of godot engine.

I found solution from godot github repo.

**Answer :** To generate custom binary for custom module you need same version of `godot engine` and same version `source code` of engine. In my case i solve using `Godot 3.1` stable version for engine and source.

Here is [link](https://github.com/atologist-pratik/CustomBuildForGodot) that provide step-by-step explanation of compile process.

Full Tutorial for Facebook Module Compile is here : [Link](https://www.iopetrcik.in/compile-facebook-module-in-godot-engine/)

Comment: You might want to give the gist of it in the Answer instead of redirecting users to an external site. Right now, it can be considered as a link only answer. You can keep the link, but it shouldn't be the highlight of the Answer.

Comment: I am doing everything by the book to build iOS custom module for Godot 3.2.1. The "Engine.has_singleton" always returns NULL for me.

Comment: @bashan can show you code ?

Comment: The code of the custom module is on Git: https://github.com/DrMoriarty/godot-facebook. I am calling it on my script this way: if (Engine.has_singleton("GodotFacebook")):